# AWS: EB CLI create command: parameter explaining

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-vpc

I want to deploy an environment to EB via the command line on my machine; so I used the following command:

```
eb create django-env --vpc.id vpc-02a9477474b131595 --vpc.elbsubnets subnet-089ebed3884dd1aae,subnet-066970ae14d53cfa0 --vpc.ec2subnets subnet-0669ffe1c35fdfa0 --vpc.securitygroup sg-0b0f43dc3e6109230
```

I want to ask about the following parameter **--vpc.ec2subnets** : should I create EC2 instances in the VPC then supply their address to the command ?

I'm following the example on this page:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-create.html#eb3-createexample1

Comment: What's wrong with the current command? Any errors?

Comment: @Marcin yes; it insists that the "Load Balance" subnets must be in different regions; my subnets are in different AZs and I double checked.